# main() function argument storage?

Tags: c

I would like to know Where arugment passed to main() gets stored in memory ,Do they simply get  store in stack .If so then how k's value  is initialize in below code

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main(int k)
 {
 if(k<10)
 printf("%d ",main(k+1));
 return k;
 }

O/p: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2
```

Comment: It should be noted that `int main(int k)` isn't really guaranteed to work by the standard. `k` will usually be `argc` as the signature `int main(int argc, char **argv)` would expect, but the above code is well golfed and shouldn't actually be expected to work.

Comment: still not get the desired anwser!!

Comment: `int main(int)` is not a valid signature in the standard, but can be valid if the implementation specifies it. Therefore, the implementation can specify that signature to mean whatever it likes, so _technically_ it can be initialized any way the implementation likes. In practice it will usually be the value of `argc` in the standard signature `int main(int, char **)`, which is 1 when the program is called with no arguments.

Comment: Thanks @Chris ,that makes some sense

Comment: k gets stored on the stack or in a register by the caller. The initial caller is startup code that invokes main.

Comment: Strictly speaking, int main(int k) would perfectly fine in a freestanding implementation of the standard (although it wouldn't make much sense). In a hosted system, the parameters of main can be void, or argv-argc, or some implementation-defined parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It'll typically be stored wherever parameters to other functions get stored -- which might be stack, register, or somewhere else entirely. Just for a few examples: on a SPARC, it'll almost certainly be a register; on an x86 (in 32-bit mode) it'll typically be the stack; on an IBM mainframe, it'll normally be in a stack frame that's dynamically allocated from the heap and linked together into a linked list that's constructed/destroyed FIFO fashion.

Also note that it can/does vary even on a single machine with a single compiler -- e.g., Microsoft VC++ can pass it on the stack or in a register depending on what compiler flag(s) you use. When/if you pass it in a register, it'll (probably) be pushed on the stack inside the function anyway (to allow the recursion).

As an aside, I'll also note that while <strike>your code</strike>calling `main` is perfectly legal C, you are not allowed to call `main` in C++.

Edit: As for the initial value, that first parameter is traditionally called `argc`, and tells you how many arguments were passed on the command line. If you invoke it (as you apparently have) with no command line, it should normally start out as `1` (the one argument being the name of the program itself, traditionally passed as `argv[0]`). If, for example, you invoked the program something like:

```
prog a b c d e f g h i j k l m
```

It would normally exit without printing anything, because on the first entry to `main`, the parameter would be greater than 10 so the body of the `if` statement would never execute.

Comment: That code is perfectly legal C on platforms that specify `int main(int)` as a valid signature for `main`. While that undoubtedly works on many compilers, I have a feeling few actually bother guaranteeing it.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, that's true. I should have been more clear: calling `main` (with a supported signature) is allowed in C, but not C++.

Comment: Jerry Thanks ,you made the things quite clear and simple in your edit section

Comment: Thi doesn't really answer the question, which is how do the arguments to the initial call to main get set. For that, you need to talk about crt0 on linux or analogous startup code on other systems.

Comment: Actually for x86 it basically depends on what calling convention you're using: With __fastcall with MSVC the first two parameters will be stored in ecx/edx, but fastcall isn't standardized.

Answer (score 1):

parameters to main() are like arguments to any other method. They are part of the stack (depending on the processor, that could be in memory, or in a CPU register). In this case, when you call main(k+1), the result of k+1 is put on the stack before the recursive call is performed.

<s>Note that the behavior of this is undefined since calling main() from within a C program is unspecified.</s>

Comment: calling `main` in C is perfectly fine. It's in C++ that it's not allowed/supported.

Comment: @James what i wanted to know is from where k is taking its initial value??

Comment: usually, it is a command line argument. I'm not certain if C is defiend to start main's arg at 1 if it is not provided by the system

Comment: @Amit For linux, see the `exec` system call. In short, the system builds a process image that contains the argument strings in the data segment, and some assembly language startup code (crt0.o) in the image that invokes main with the argument count (int argc) and a pointer to the argument strings (char** argv) as arguments. Since you have defined main incorrectly, the value of k isn't well-defined; it may be the value of argc or it may be an integer representation of argv or it may be garbage or the program may crash.

Comment: So what you want to say is this program's behavior is undefined??